# Is it possible to initialize some of the fields in a mock object

Tags: java, android, testing, junit, mockito

I have a code that I cannot correctly cover with tests.
I am using the Mockito library.
And I had difficulty at the moment of starting the test.

Below is the test code:

```
@Test
public void testLoadCar() {
    when(remoteService.loadData()).thenReturn(new DataResult<DataCar>("", "", new DataCar()));
    when(dataResult.hasError()).thenReturn(true);
    when(dataResult.response.hasHeaders()).thenReturn(true);
    requestNetwork = new RequestNetwork(remoteService);
    Response<DataCar> response = requestNetwork.load(request);
}
```

These are objects in the test class: remoteService, dataResult, request.

I am concerned about the moment where I am trying to implement the when method:

```
when(dataResult.response.hasHeaders()).thenReturn(true);
```

I would like to know if such a recording will work.
If it doesn't work, then how can we handle this moment:

```
protected Response createResponse(DataResult<T> dataResult) {
    if (dataResult.hasError()  || !dataResult.response.hasHeaders()) {
        return dataResult.getErrorMessage());
    } else {
        return Response.data(dataResult.value);
    }
}
```

This is a method on the system under test (SUT) that has a createResponse() method. This method contains a call to the mock method of the DataResult object.
To implement dataResult.hasError () I got it:

```
when (dataResult.hasError ()). thenReturn (true);
```

Then with! DataResult.response.hasHeaders () I have a problem. Since I don't understand how to substitute the value I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all objects that your object under test interacts with need to be mocks.
Remember that you can use POJOs as well.

`DataResult` looks like a perfect candidate for a POJO.
You gain nothing by using a mock objet if you can create a POJO with desired state and behaviour.

Looking at the posted code, it looks like it is easy to create:

```
new DataResult<DataCar>("", "", new DataCar())
```

On top of that:

Your code looks suspicious to me.

- when stubbing `remoteService.loadData()` you create a new instance of `DataResult`
- subsequently, you stub some calls on `dataResult`, which is not an object returned from `remoteService.loadData()`

And to answer original post:

You can set fields on mocks (directly if access modifiers allow it, or via reflection otherwise). Note that this is highly not-idiomatic and surprising use of mocks.

```java
class A {
    B b;
}

class B {
    boolean hasHeaders() {
        return true;
    }
}

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class AAATest {

    @Mock
    A aMock;

    @Mock
    B bMock;

    @BeforeEach
    void setupMocks() {
        aMock.b = bMock;
    }

    @Test
    void testFieldInMockIsInitialized() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(bMock, aMock.b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!